# Which filesystem has high-performance, low-reliability characteristics?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am running a job on a CentOS virtual machine that uses tens of thousands of temporary files.  This leads to I/O being the major bottleneck for this job running quickly.  The total size of the temporary files is quite large and can exceed available RAM.

Because the job is being run on a VM, and because all files are temporary, I don't care about any kind of reliability.  If power fails, the VM is trashed anyway.  If a process crashes, the VM is trashed anyway.  No more than one process will be accessing these files.  Also, the files will never be deleted - the VM is trashed at the end of the run.

It sounds to me like I don't need most of the features of existing filesystems (journaling, locking, bitmapping), but I do need basic filesystem characteristics.  My question is, which filesystem is best at providing just the bare-bones file system features, without all the bells and whistles?  It stands to reason that such a filesystem would also significantly improve performance because it wouldn't have to deal with all those things.

Note: Unfortunately, I didn't write the job and I can't control its tempfile behavior.

Comment: Can you run the job on a vfat-partition? Is the job a script or an exe?

Comment: It sounds like a good match for RAID-0 to effectively; write speeds can often come quite close to the theoretical maximum doubling. SSDs are well versed for random writes. If you can throw money at it, dual SSDs in RAID-0 scales well for the price, or you can just buy a large amount of RAM and run it in a RAM disk. It's usually not as expensive as it might sound, within reasonable boundaries. I would not think that file system changes in itself will be able to give improvements as large as those ones.

Answer (score 0):

ext2 is the most barebone in linux, if you can live with its restrictions such as size. you may find even more barebone ones (minix?) but I would not really recommend it because they are too ancient. by the way, give a lot of memory for caching if you can afford to, or even just use a ramdisk.

Comment: It is entirely possible to run ext3 and/or ext4 without journaling, and get the same kind of performance.  Take a look at the [tune2fs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man8/tune2fs.8.html) options.  I would disable not only journaling, but also `uninit_bg`, `filetype`, and also make sure that it's mounted with `noatime`.  This should get similar performance to that of ext2 without the drawbacks.